# System panic when set multiple '1' in GICv2 GICD_ITARGETSRn in ARMv7

Tags: multiprocessing, arm, interrupt

I am working on a AliOS-Things project with an ARMv7 SOC (2cores).
And now I want to change GICD_ITARGETSRn to distrubite one interrupt to multiple cores by setting 011b,  but the system will crash when interrupt is enabled.

I think there should be something wrong in the RTOS kernel to deal with this case or I missed something in GICv2 configuration or I did something wrong in this case.

So what is the key point to distrubite 1 IRQ to multiple cores and handle it in only in one CPU, without introducing race conditions.

I am not sure if it is correct to set multiple 1s in GICD_ITARGETSRn for one interrupt.

Comment: You might get more help if you edit the question and add a tag for the particular RTOS you are using.

Comment: Updated the original question.

Comment: Would you have a link to the source code of the exact version of AliOS-Things you are using, or did you port it to the target CPU yourself ?

Comment: Here is the github of AliOS-things, https://github.com/alibaba/AliOS-Things, and the SOC vendor did their porting. By default, all interrupts target to CPU0, and I want to change 1 IRQ to CPU0 and CPU1. But I am not sure if this is the right way to do that (I think APIC in X86 can support this). By reading GICv2 spec, GICD_ITARGETSRn could be set '0bxxxxxxx1' for CPU0, etc. It seemed setting multiple 1s is valid and supported. But If I set the GICD_ITARGETSRn for the IRQ to '0bxxxxxx11' the OS will panic......

Comment: Since the SoC vendor is not making its port available, this is like you were asking for support on a closed-source, proprietary operating system. Only the current users of this port, who may well be your competitors, would be able to answer/help you. Is there any license-related information in the source code responsible for managing the GIC that would allow retrieving the original code from its primary source ?

Comment: In this case, it is related to GICv2 configuration, which should be an ARM generic question. So the better way is to ask here or ARM if it is valid to set multiple '1' in GICD_ITARGETSRn. If it is valid, then I will escalate the panic to the OS and BSP vendor.